# Google sheets edit trigger email sheet range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

can anyone help me get sheet by name before the if conditional? I'm trying to limit the range to column C on a specific sheet and right now it gets triggered by all sheets.

```
function sendMailEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart!= 3 || e.value != "REMOVAL") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,14).getValues();
  let n = rData[0][3];
  let f = rData[0][1];
  let d = rData[0][13];
  let items = rData[0][2];
  let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
  
  let msg = "This is an auto generated message to inform you that the removal date of " + f + " for project " + n + " (" + d + ") has been added to the Logistics Schedule at " + now;
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("x@x.com", "Project Removal Scheduled", msg)
}
```

I tried adding getSheetByName on line 3 and the trigger still worked with all other sheets but with no data. Also on line 2 I added e.source.set or get SheetByName etc no success.

Answer (score 1):

```
function sendMailEdit(e){
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() != "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart!= 3 || e.value != "REMOVAL") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,14).getValues();
  let n = rData[0][3];
  let f = rData[0][1];
  let d = rData[0][13];
  let items = rData[0][2];
  let now = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US");
  
  let msg = "This is an auto generated message to inform you that the removal date of " + f + " for project " + n + " (" + d + ") has been added to the Logistics Schedule at " + now;
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("x@x.com", "Project Removal Scheduled", msg)
}
```

Comment: Can you also help me fix the date, please? it's coming out too long: Wed Feb 22 2023 09:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) how do I turn it into this: Wed Feb 22 2023?

Comment: I would use setNumberFormat() in the range class